# EditorFileDialog or FileDialog popup from EditorScript

Tags: godot

hello Godot's comunity !

I try to integrate in a project a way to import custom json file to generate Tilemap. So I use a EditorScript to generate it but now I want to open a file dialog popup to choose specific file in my disk. So i tried something like this :

```
tool
extends EditorScript
func _run():

    var fileDialog = EditorFileDialog.new()
    fileDialog.mode = EditorFileDialog.MODE_OPEN_FILE
    fileDialog.access = EditorFileDialog.ACCESS_FILESYSTEM  
    fileDialog.popup()
    ...
```

but nothing happened. Only this in debugger :

```
scene/gui/control.cpp:2154 - Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true.
scene/2d/canvas_item.cpp:469 - Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true. Returned: get_transform()
scene/2d/canvas_item.cpp:939 - Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true. Returned: Rect2()
scene/gui/control.cpp:2128 - Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true.
scene/gui/control.cpp:2128 - Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true.
./scene/main/node.h:269 - Condition "!data.tree" is true. Returned: nullptr
```

Any idea to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the FileDialog a viewport to be shown in.

You do so by getting the viewport of the editor:

```
var viewport = get_editor_interface().get_editor_viewport()
viewport.add_child(fileDialog)
```

this will show the dialog, but to ensure you do not run into followup problems:
The editor script is freed soon after running the run function, so connected signals will be not fired after choosing a file. (See [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/27041))

In the issue is the solution to secure the connected functions in the script are fired, by keeping the instance in the dialog. After you finished you should free the dialog to make sure you can run the script again, without closing the whole editor.

Complete code would look something like this:

```
tool
extends EditorScript

var fileDialog : EditorFileDialog = null

func _run():
    fileDialog = EditorFileDialog.new()
    fileDialog.mode = EditorFileDialog.MODE_OPEN_FILE
    fileDialog.access = EditorFileDialog.ACCESS_FILESYSTEM
    fileDialog.connect("file_selected", self, "on_file_selected")
    var viewport = get_editor_interface().get_editor_viewport()
    viewport.add_child(fileDialog)
    fileDialog.set_meta("_created_by", self) # needed so the script is not directly freed after the run function. Would disconnect all signals otherwise
    fileDialog.popup(Rect2(0,0, 700, 500)) # Giving the dialog a predefined size
    print("end")
    
    
func on_file_selected(filename : String) :
    print(filename)
    if (fileDialog != null):
        fileDialog.queue_free() # Dialog has to be freed in order for the script to be called again.
```

Comment: I just found a solution to display the popup [here](https://godotengine.org/qa/57137/how-to-browse-files-using-a-editorplugin) but I discovered the problem of the signal connection and your solution works perfectly